# Can't update values in table TD using AJAX and PHP returned JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP-AJAX script to delete an existing financial rows from a table. PHP script is working fine and the rows are being deleted. But the problem is inside the `success` function of `AJAX` call. First let me show you the table:

[image]

Forget about the delete payment button and concentrate on the Delete Project. When clicking on it, I want to delete all the project with the already paid payments and everything is working properly until I need to update the `Total`, `Still to Pay`, and `Total Paid`.

The `Total` cell is updated properly but when I can't update the others. I will see `NaN $` in them.

[image]

Here is the script:

```
    success:function(resp)
    {
      var pay_total = 0;
      row.fadeOut(700);

      //updating the total TD:
      var totalVal = parseInt($("#final_cash").text());
      var NewTotal = totalVal - parseInt(proj_cost);
      $("#final_cash").text(NewTotal +' $');

      //$.each because I have multiple rows returned from PHP 
      //and each row represent a payment in a different date.

      $.each(resp, function(key, row)
      {
        $("#"+row.debt_id).fadeOut(600);

        //Updating the still to pay TD:
        var pay_total = parseInt(pay_total) + parseInt(row.payment);
        console.log(pay_total);//The result is NaN
        var still_cash_t = parseInt($("#still_cash").text());
        var sct = pay_total + still_cash_t;
        $("#still_cash").text(sct + ' $');

        //Updating the Total Paid TD:
        var paid_cash_t = parseInt($("#paid_cash").text());
        var pct = paid_cash_t - pay_total;
        $("#paid_cash").text(pct +' $');
      });
    },
```

Comment: OT: You are using 3 different naming conventions in one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `var` in:

```
var pay_total = parseInt(pay_total) + parseInt(row.payment);
```

to avoid redeclaration of variable `pay_total` inside `function(key, row) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you adding or may be subtracting into json value, that's why it is showing Nan, it seems it behaving like string value if you convert it into number then this problem can be resolve. convert it into number before adding/subtracting some value